# Hide TreeView root node in WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, treeview

Can someone tell me how to hide the root node of a TreeView in WPF/Silverlight? I would still like to display hierarchical data and to be able to expand collapse nodes except for the root node (which shouldn't be displayed at all).

Regards,

Xam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to have a single root node?

If not you could create all your items at the top level.

---

```
<TreeView>
  <TreeViewItem Header='First'>
    <TreeViewItem Header='sub' />
  </TreeViewItem>
  <TreeViewItem Header='Second'>
    <TreeViewItem Header='sub' />
  </TreeViewItem>
  <TreeViewItem Header='Third'>
    <TreeViewItem Header='sub' />
  </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DataTrigger that makes the root node collapsed

This link may help:
http://www.beacosta.com/2006/05/how-can-i-change-way-data-_114702952170041155.html

Comment: If I collapse the root node, won't that make all other nodes disappear too?